# OpenID Connect: How to retrieve user info and create principle after authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have a asp.net Core RazorPages project I am working on that requires OpenID Connect for authentication and pulling user information. I am not terribly familiar with this protocol, to be honest, and while I have the login working I am kind of lost as to what happens next.

Within my startup class, I have implemented the following code. This configuration was provided to me by the company that is behind the identity server I am connecting to.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", o =>
                {
                    o.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                    o.ClientId = Configuration["PmIdentity:ClientId"]; // id of external application. Should be also configured on Policy Management Identity Provider side
                    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["PmIdentity:ClientSecret"]; // related secret. Should be also configured on Policy Management Identity Provider side

                    o.ResponseType = "code id_token"; // hybrid flow.

                    o.Authority = Configuration["PmIdentity:Url"];
                    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    o.SaveTokens = true;

                    o.Scope.Add("pm_api");
                    o.Scope.Add("profile");
                    o.Scope.Add("permission");
                    o.Scope.Add("product");
                    o.Scope.Add("role");

                    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("permission", "permission");
                    o.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");
                });

            services.AddAuthorization();   
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();        
        }
```

When I run the application, it correctly sends me to the login page and I am able to authenticate. But its not clear to me what kind of principle is being created by the OIDC framework, or how to query its properties.

Likewise, I believe that the "o.Scope.Add()" statements are telling the server what information about the user I am going to request and not necessarily asking the server to immediately return that. From what I have read, it seems that I would call the UserInfo endpoint to get that data (they do have this implemented) and pass in the JWT. But again, its not clear to me how I would access the JWT returned by the initial authentication request.

I have tried looking online, but most of the information and examples I find relate to OpenID 2.0 and not OpenID Connect, which my reading tells me are different animals with similar names. Hopefully, someone here with more experience in this matter can provide an example, or a link to a helpful resource, that can clarify this process for me?

As always, TIA.

Comment: I’m afraid this question is a bit too broad. I’d suggest you to read the [docs on authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). In the end, the OIDC scheme integrates directly with the authentication system in ASP.NET Core so you do not need to worry about protocol details. Also, OIDC is used for the identity, so you do not need to care about tokens that are used in the protocol flow. With the authentication, you have access to the user principal object and that will have all the claims that were passed by the identity provider.

Comment: Check out this site, https://openid.net/connect/